# Custom camera with UIImagePickerController and AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I have a custom camera on my app. I have added a button on the camera view so the user can pick images from their album if they want. Once they choose an image, they crop it into a square then reaches the edit screen. The problem I am having is once user crops the image and taps "done", it segues back to the camera instead of going to the edit screen.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
    //isAlbum = NO;
    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [def objectForKey:@"imageData"];
    if([NSStringFromClass([data class]) isEqualToString:@"NSData"]){
        [self performSeague];
    }
//    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.cameraView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setupAVCapture];
    [self setLatestPicture];
    [_AlbumView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [_AlbumView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraOverlay.png"]]];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:overlayView];
  }
  else{
      [self performSeague];
  }
```

`[self performSeague]` segues to a UIImagePickerController(different controller). Here is the code for it's delegate

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
  UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]init];
  data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"imageData"];

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pictureSelectedSeague" sender:self];


  }
 -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cancelSeage" sender:self];
   }];

  }
```

Here if the user cancels, I segue back to the camera and it works but when the user is done picking the edited image, instead of following `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pictureSelectedSeague" sender:self];` this line of code, it dismisses the picker and gets back to the camera view.

Answer (score -1):

dismiss imagepicker model view in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method using code below`[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: Same outcome. And `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is deprecated.